# dropdown menu bootstrap active

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu on my homepage but the dropdown menu is always active. I'm using this code. What is wrong with it?

This is the part of the drop down code I'm using:

```
<li class="dropdown" class="" itemprop="name" >
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        </li>
```

It's always active when I open the page and not when I click it to drop down.

Comment: You will need to include the javascript files to make it interactive.

Comment: In the future, please provide a minimal, verifiable example or a jsFiddle with your question. If you had done that you would have known that this code is perfectly fine and your issue is somewhere else. https://jsfiddle.net/w3rm4mhy/

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here full code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```